# Check a directory for all files of a certain filetype

Tags: python

I am having trouble checking a directory for all files of a certain filetype in python, .wav to be specific.

I have tried a few different methods to solve the problem but can't seem to tackle it. Is there any way in python to check a directory like this?

Comment: If you show your current attempts it should be possible to fix them...

Comment: ok sry, I will bear that in mind next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will make a list of all the filenames and then check if they end with .wav

```
import os

listdirectory = os.listdir(".") # gets the name of all files in your dir
for filename in listdirectory: 
    if filename.endswith(".wav"): # check each of the files for whether or not they end in .wav
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, I will upvote it when I have enough points to click the up button

Answer (score 4):

```
import os    

files = os.listdir(path) #returns a list of files in the given directory

for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(".wav"):
        doSomething
```

Comment: What's with calling it `_file`? To avoid the builtin that's removed in Python 3? Just call it `filename` or `fname` or something :)

Comment: @JonClements Fair enough.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, I will upvote it when I have enough points to click the up button

Answer (score 4):

Use [`iglob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
import glob

search_for = '/foo/bar/*/*.wav'
for i in glob.iglob(search_for):
    print(i)
```